# Using local macros in names of global macros

Tags: global, stata, local, stata-macros

How can I use local macros in the names of global macros in Stata 14?

For example:

```
global test1 = 250
local n = 1

. di $test1 // works
250

. di $test`n' // does not work (should be 250 and not 1)
1
```

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please consider up-voting it using the upper arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [18 Programming Stata](https://www.stata.com/manuals/u18.pdf#u18.3.10)  Manual explains:

> *"...You  can  mix  global  and  local  macros.  Assume  that  local  macro j
>   contains 7. Then, ${x`j’} expands to the contents of $x7..."*

So you just need to use curly brackets `{}` in your global macro:

```
. global test1 = 250
. local n = 1

. display $test1
250

. display ${test`n'}
250
```